# How to create character creation pipeline that use the same rig proportions?

Tags: animation, rigging

Does anyone know a good workflow or tutorial on how to create the same rig proportions for both a male and female character? Using Auto Rig Pro, it's been great. But, having big issues when needing to transfer animation from one character to another. Doesn't work, way too much cleanup to be something I can move forward with. Auto Rig pro devs have mentioned that if the rigs have same proportions animations would transfer seamlessly. But, I'm stumped. How can the rigs be the same proportion if the characters are not the same proportions? .FBX export > transfer to second rig has been terrible as well. Looking for ability to copy action from one rig (character) to another. Any help much much appreciated.

Comment: No, characters with different proportions cannot have rigs with the same proportions.  This, that animations don't necessarily transfer well,  is a fact of life.  There is no generalizable rigging solution.  Animation might have a character bend her clavicle to touch her nose, or bend her clavicle to dance the M in YMCA, and one depends on both arm and nose length and one doesn't really depend on anything, and the animation doesn't contain any of that info about what the pose is doing in a functional sense.

Comment: Thx Nathan for the response. Knowing that it's simply a "fact of life" with animation as it is now, and not something I'm missing or doing wrong, is helpful in itself.